# trying yo update my JFrame

Tags: java, swing

In my Frame i have have a title screen(J Panel) and when i click a button i want it to be replaced with the game screen(another J Panel). i have this code to replace it, but when i click the button to send it to my start method it clears the GUI and it just stays blank.

```
public void start() {
         frame.remove(titlePanel);
         frame.repaint();
         frame.add(gamePanel);
}
```

if i add the gamePanel to the frame where i did the titlePanel it works fine so i know it is finding the image.

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A preferred solution would be to use [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which will allow you to switch out views easily...

The direct approach (which you are doing now) should be fixed by calling `frame.revalidate()` after you've added the `gamePanel`...but I'd still recommend the `CardLayout`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `frame.revalidate()` to get changes working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    JPanel panel1;
    JPanel panel2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    test frame = new test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);

         panel2 = new JPanel();
         panel2.setBackground(Color.blue);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                remove(panel1);
                contentPane.add(panel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                repaint();
                validate();
            }
        });
    }

}
```